# How do I kill the Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria-console

I've been playing Terraria for exactly one week now.  I've beaten: Eye of Cthulhu, Eater of Worlds, King Slime, and Skeletron. I use a full set of [Molten armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Molten_armor), [Lightning boots](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lightning_Boots), [Cloud in a Balloon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cloud_in_a_Balloon), and an [Ivy Whip](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ivy_Whip). I use the [Fiery Greatsword](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fiery_Greatsword), [Muramasa](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Muramasa), [Star Cannon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Star_Cannon), [Water Bolt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Bolt), and [Minishark](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Minishark).

I need help on killing the [Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh).  I've tried building a hell bridge but every time he spawns backwards, so I have to fly over lava which usually kills me. I play on Xbox 360.

Comment: I don't know anything about this game but have you tried the [strategies on the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Wall_of_Flesh_strategies)?  I don't see any mention of a hell bridge, so that may not be the right direction.  If those don't work for you, you may want to update the question with what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: @Brythan Do we really need edits that turn a question into link spam?  I can see one or two, but we don't need that many.

Comment: @hotlinecalifornia I'm having trouble seeing how this is at all a dupe of *Truffles*, of all things.

Comment: @Frank I closed as dupe of my question. Someone else must have done it.

Answer (score 2):

You say that "every time he spawns backwards." Wherever you spawn it, the Wall of Flesh always travels toward the middle of the world. So if you spawn it close to one end of the Underworld, you can be assured that it will go the right way: away from the edge of the world, giving you lots of space. Other than that, just bring a good piercing weapon (Minishark with Meteor Shot and Water Bolt are both great choices); a rapid-fire weapon is fine because the Wall has very low defense.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fight the Wall of Flesh is to prepare first.

- Build a LONG platform from blocks you have in excess (I used the candy cane blocks).
- Break a hole in the middle of the platform, then throw the doll in.
- Try throwing the doll in the lava with your back facing the side you want the boss to spawn on if the Wall spawns backwards.

Sidenote: Your weapons are good, as well as your armor. Just stay far enough away from him, and you'll be fine.

Don't get too far away though, or you'll die instantly from a debuff he gives you called "Horrified".