# How do I defeat the Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria-console

I am not sure how to fight The Wall of Flesh. I have Meteor Armour, a Minishark, Star-cannon and Space Gun. I've tried once and wasn't able to kill it. What is the best strategy to defeat the Wall of Flesh?

Comment: Should you?  We can't answer that.  If you *want* to beat the Wall of Flesh, *that*, we can help you with: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188524/how-do-i-kill-the-wall-of-flesh

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, however a more thorough answer may be required for both questions.